# Pointcloud to LaserScan for Navigation

Tags: imu, navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to do navigation for my mobile robot. I have an IMU, wheel encoder and laser scanner. For this, I guess, I have to convert pointcloud to laserscan. Do you have any idea about this converting. I looked at http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan page. But I didn't understand anything. Please help me about this situation

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294315/pointcloud-to-laserscan-for-navigation/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2018-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-06-17**:
You're going to need to be a little more specific on what you don't understand. Have you tried running the node? Do you understand the difference between a PointCloud2 msg and a LaserScan msg?

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-06-18**:
In my study, I transformed the laserscan message into a point cloud to obtain a three-dimensional image of the environment and obtained a three-dimensional image of the environment with a vertical scanning plane. But I suppose you need a laserscan message with a horizontal scan plane to navigate.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-06-18**:
@stevejp So I know I need to make a conversion to the laser from the point cloud. Am I right?

**Comment by [PratNag](https://answers.ros.org/users/28957/pratnag/) on 2018-06-19**:
What sensor are you using? Are you using a 2d lidar, a 3d lidar or a kinect camera?  If you have a laser scanner it directly gives output as LasersScan msg which is needed for the navigation stack.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-06-19**:
Yes, I use a 2d laser scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

which is the scanner you are using? The output is usually ideally laserscan msg under /scan topic. If you get pointcloud msg you can do something like this. This is example for using kinect as a fake laser scanner source.

```
 <node pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan" name="depthimage_to_laserscan">
  <remap from="image"     to="/camera/depth/depth_registered"/>
  <remap from="camera_info" to="/camera/depth/camera_info"/>
  <remap from="scan" to="/scan"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [PratNag](https://answers.ros.org/users/28957/pratnag/) with karma: 61 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-06-19**:
Mr. @PratNag I am using hokuyo urg-04lx-ug01 laser scanner. Yes ı can get laserscan msg but ı converted laserscan into pointcloud. Now, for navigation I guess I have to convert this pointcloud to laserscan? havent  ı?

**Comment by [PratNag](https://answers.ros.org/users/28957/pratnag/) on 2018-06-19**:
No you dont need to. You can use the laserscan topic from hokoyu directly for navigation stack. The original msg published by the laser scanner is not modified when you convert it to pointcloud.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-06-19**:
Thank you Mr. @PratNag